# Is it possible to type a macron inside a HTML textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I'm validating a HTML textbox field`<input type="text" />`, and I need to detect if the user has entered a Macron in the textbox. My question is that is there any way to TYPE (Not copy-paste) a Macron into an HTML textbox?? 
If so, how would you detect if the user has typed a Macron?

I've checked [this page](http://www.personal.psu.edu/ejp10/psu/gotunicode/macron.html). At the bottom, it's shown how to type it, but I couldn't.

Comment: What's a "macron"? *edit* oh ok ...

Comment: macron: A short, straight, horizontal diacritical mark placed over a vowel. It usually is used to indicate that the pronunciation of the vowel is long, in Mandarin pinyin (Chinese), it indicates the first tone, e.g. chūzūchē.

Comment: You could make a regular expression that looks for the Unicode characters that include that diacritical mark I guess.

Comment: @Pointy: yes, but is there any way to type it into the textbox?

Comment: @Pointy:a line over the letters A, E, I, O U, a, e, i, o, u. Eg: Ā,Ū

Comment: You read this part, right? : **NOTE: Your page should declare utf-8 (Unicode) encoding or else the characters may not display in older browsers. Because these are Unicode characters, the formatting may not exactly match that of the surrounding text depending on the browser.**

Comment: @karank I suspect it's possible, yes. It can certainly be pasted, and there's really not much difference between pasting text and typing it. Remember that your HTML form may be managed by *any* piece of software, so you really have no idea what people may be up to.

Comment: @Pointy I think he means "&#256;" instead of "Ā".

Comment: Just use an `onchange` event, and get the last char each time, then do `this.value.charCodeAt(this.value.length-1)`, and check the numeric value of the character, for example: `'ē'.charCodeAt(0)` is 275 etc...

Comment: @karank if you provided more contextual information concerning *why* you need to check for this, it might help get answers.

Comment: Also, detecting that a user has typed a "macron" is not different from detecting any specific input. (Right?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with
[Alt Codes](http://www.wouterlowies.nl/voorbeeld/chars/)

Alt-0175 Gives a macron ¯ in a input field.

However, i dont know how to combite the macron with a character, but that wasn't the question.

*EDIT :*
found these ALT codes for macron characters. (only work in Word)

Lowercase Vowels

- ā    ALT+0257 Lower long A
- ē    ALT+0275 Lower long E
- ī    ALT+0299 Lower long I
- ō    ALT+0333 Lower long O
- ū    ALT+0363 Lower long U
- ȳ    ALT+0562 Lower long Y
- æ    ALT+0230 Lower AE lig
- œ    ALT+0156 Lower OE lig

Capital Vowels

- Ā    ALT+0256 Cap long A
- Ē    ALT+0274 Cap long E
- Ī    ALT+0298 Cap long I
- Ō    ALT+0332 Cap long O
- Ū    ALT+0362 Cap long U
- Ȳ    ALT+0563 Cap long Y
- Æ    ALT+0198 Cap AE lig
- Œ    ALT+0140 Cap OE lig

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should always assume that users can type any character in a textbox. This is true no matter what you mean by “macron” here. It could mean U+00AF MACRON “¯”, or U+0304 COMBINING MACRON, or macron as part of a character as in U+0101 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH MACRON “ā”.

For example, using a normal Finnish keyboard with a keyboard driver that conforms to the modern Finnish standard, I typed “¯” using just AltGr ¨ space and “ā” using AltGr ¨ A. Entering the combining macron is possible using e.g. my own keyboard driver for combining marks or the “universal method” described on the Fileformat.info page [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm).

You can detect a macron, in any meaning, by inspecting the value of the field. When using JavaScript, you can e.g. check whether the value contains `\u00af` (if you are not sure how to enter “¯” directly into your code and ensure that it is reas properly).